# How does Logistic regression classifier modelize the dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic

I'm working on a system that be able to detect the hand contour. So I have 270 instance in my dataset: 7 class of hand  contour, 8 feature vectors of each instance.
Firstly, I used Weka to determine which is the best classifier for my dataset. And I found out Logistic regression classifier.
But, the problem is I don't know 'How does the Logistic regression classifier work?' or 'WHAT IS THE MAIN PONIT (IDEA) OF LOGISTIC REGRESSION CLASSIFIER?'. I've been searching on google for a long time but I still can't find the answer.
Here's what I've found that should be useful:
1 1992-JSTOR-Cessie-Logistic_Regression
[2] [Chapter 4 Logistic Regression as a Classiﬁer]1

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Logistic classifier is a linear classifier. It uses 'Least Square' to adjust the f(x) function, which classify the 2 class.
 Instead of predict the class, the classifier predict the probability of class Y being 1 with knowing X.
In my problem, the Logistic regression model uses Newton algorithm instead of  'Least Square'. It builds a matrix to adjust the function. 
To classifying 7 class, it needs to have 7 logistic function, where each logistic predict the probability of one class.
That's how I've got.